# Matrix must contain at least 3 different values

Tags: matlab

I have a `matrix <1x100>` named test containing values such as: 10,10,30,50,50,30,30,10,40,...

Is it possible to check whether the matrix contains at least 3 variations of numbers, for the example I showed it would evaluate to true since we have 10, 30, 50. In another example: 10,10,10,20,10,20,10,10... it should give false since we only have 10 and 20.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try unique command in Matlab. It will give you unique elements in the array and then you can check if its length is 3 or more as per your criteria.

```
length(unique(a))
```

length will give you the number of unique elements... This will help to check if it is 3 or more

Comment: good answer, maybe you could consider writing 2 lines of code to give an example of how to use the `unique` function

Comment: @user6460588 please consider to edit and improve your answer

Comment: length will give you the number of unique elements... This will help to check  if it is 3 or more